# ffmpeg: audio loss when overlaying videos of different lengths

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have two videos of different length, each with stereo audio, that I have overlayed using ffmpeg. I have assigned the audio from the two videos to the left and right channel, respectively, of the output video.

Here is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -filter_complex "amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3;blend=all_expr='A*0.5+B*0.5'" output.mp4
```

The trouble is, this cuts the audio from both input videos once the shorter video has stopped playing, which is documented behavior for the `amerge` filter. It also, spits out lots of these errors --

`Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory`

-- though it does complete processing. I've tried simply leaving out the amerge filter

```
 ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -filter_complex "pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3;blend=all_expr='A*0.5+B*0.5'" output.mp4
```

but the output from that doesn't include the audio from the second video. How would this be done properly? Sorry for the noob question, only started using ffmpeg this week.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[Edit] Here is the error message-riddled output for the command mentioned above:

`C:\Users\admin\Downloads\ffmpeg-20170110-f48b6b8-win64-static\ffmpeg-20170110-f4
8b6b8-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg -i v01.mp4 -i v02.mp4 -filter_complex "amerge=inpu
ts=2,pan=stereo|c1<c0+c1|c0<c2+c3;blend=all_expr='A*0.5+B*0.5'" out1.mp4 > outpu
t.txt
ffmpeg version N-83034-gf48b6b8 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx -
-enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei
0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-li
bbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --en
able-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-li
bopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --e
nable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable
-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --e
nable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavcodec     57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavformat    57. 62.100 / 57. 62.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 68.100 /  6. 68.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'v01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.62.100
    location-eng    : +37.3789-005.9891/
    location        : +37.3789-005.9891/
  Duration: 00:00:05.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4760 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080
, 4642 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 122 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'v02.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.62.100
  Duration: 00:00:15.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3766 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080
, 3632 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 126 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'out1.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0000000002325e80] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0000000002325e80] Input channel layouts overlap: output layou
t will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[libx264 @ 0000000001bff560] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0000000001bff560] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0000000001bff560] 264 - core 148 r2744 b97ae06 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.62.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.71.100 aac
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1
080, q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.71.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> blend:top
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> amerge:in0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> blend:bottom
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> amerge:in1
  pan -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
  blend -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   10 fps=9.5 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.38 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   16 fps=9.7 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.60 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   22 fps=9.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.79 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   28 fps=9.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.98 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   34 fps= 10 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.19 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   39 fps= 10 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.36 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   44 fps= 10 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.51 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   46 fps=9.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.60 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   51 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=      42kB time=00:00:01.75 bitrate= 197.4kbits/
frame=   55 fps=8.8 q=29.0 size=     147kB time=00:00:01.90 bitrate= 633.2kbits/
frame=   59 fps=8.7 q=29.0 size=     220kB time=00:00:02.02 bitrate= 888.5kbits/
frame=   63 fps=8.5 q=29.0 size=     288kB time=00:00:02.15 bitrate=1092.1kbits/
frame=   67 fps=8.4 q=29.0 size=     360kB time=00:00:02.28 bitrate=1289.4kbits/
frame=   71 fps=8.3 q=29.0 size=     435kB time=00:00:02.43 bitrate=1465.1kbits/
frame=   75 fps=8.2 q=29.0 size=     514kB time=00:00:02.56 bitrate=1642.1kbits/
frame=   79 fps=8.1 q=29.0 size=     577kB time=00:00:02.69 bitrate=1757.4kbits/
frame=   83 fps=8.1 q=29.0 size=     630kB time=00:00:02.81 bitrate=1831.7kbits/
frame=   87 fps=8.0 q=29.0 size=     695kB time=00:00:02.96 bitrate=1917.5kbits/
frame=   91 fps=8.0 q=29.0 size=     760kB time=00:00:03.09 bitrate=2011.4kbits/
frame=   95 fps=8.0 q=29.0 size=     822kB time=00:00:03.22 bitrate=2088.1kbits/
frame=   99 fps=7.9 q=29.0 size=     890kB time=00:00:03.37 bitrate=2161.8kbits/
frame=  103 fps=7.9 q=29.0 size=     968kB time=00:00:03.50 bitrate=2264.7kbits/
frame=  107 fps=7.8 q=29.0 size=    1053kB time=00:00:03.62 bitrate=2376.7kbits/
frame=  111 fps=7.8 q=29.0 size=    1124kB time=00:00:03.75 bitrate=2450.1kbits/
frame=  115 fps=7.8 q=29.0 size=    1192kB time=00:00:03.90 bitrate=2499.5kbits/
frame=  119 fps=7.8 q=29.0 size=    1251kB time=00:00:04.03 bitrate=2540.7kbits/
frame=  123 fps=7.8 q=29.0 size=    1308kB time=00:00:04.16 bitrate=2573.6kbits/
frame=  127 fps=7.8 q=29.0 size=    1365kB time=00:00:04.29 bitrate=2606.3kbits/
frame=  131 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    1432kB time=00:00:04.44 bitrate=2642.3kbits/
frame=  135 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    1488kB time=00:00:04.56 bitrate=2667.8kbits/
frame=  139 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    1542kB time=00:00:04.69 bitrate=2690.3kbits/
frame=  143 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    1595kB time=00:00:04.82 bitrate=2708.7kbits/
frame=  147 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    1645kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=2709.7kbits/
frame=  151 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    1698kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=2797.2kbits/
frame=  155 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    1756kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=2892.4kbits/
frame=  160 fps=7.6 q=29.0 size=    1833kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=3019.7kbits/
frame=  165 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    1902kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=3132.8kbits/
frame=  169 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    1954kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=3219.1kbits/
frame=  173 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    2006kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=3303.5kbits/
frame=  178 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    2066kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=3402.7kbits/
frame=  182 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    2121kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=3493.2kbits/
frame=  187 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    2187kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=3601.8kbits/
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
frame=  191 fps=7.7 q=29.0 size=    2262kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=3725.2kbits/
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
frame=  195 fps=7.6 q=29.0 size=    2344kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate=3860.9kbits/
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
.....
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
frame=  436 fps=7.9 q=29.0 size=    2466kB time=00:00:12.77 bitrate=1580.9kbits/
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
frame=  440 fps=7.9 q=29.0 size=    2466kB time=00:00:12.91 bitrate=1564.5kbits/
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while decoding stream #1:1: Cannot allocate memory
frame=  446 fps=8.0 q=29.0 size=    2466kB time=00:00:13.11 bitrate=1540.7kbits/
frame=  450 fps=8.0 q=29.0 size=    2466kB time=00:00:13.24 bitrate=1525.1kbits/
frame=  450 fps=7.7 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5298kB time=00:00:14.91 bitrate=2910.2kbits
/s speed=0.255x
video:5213kB audio:76kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
 overhead: 0.194365%
[aac @ 0000000001f5bb20] Qavg: 5159.816
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] frame I:2     Avg QP:20.68  size: 76647
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] frame P:113   Avg QP:21.48  size: 25608
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] frame B:335   Avg QP:24.65  size:  6836
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] consecutive B-frames:  0.7%  0.0%  0.7% 98.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] mb I  I16..4: 21.3% 66.8% 11.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] mb P  I16..4:  4.0%  5.3%  0.5%  P16..4: 45.0% 11.2
%  5.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:29.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.6%  0.6%  0.0%  B16..8: 35.6%  2.3
%  0.2%  direct: 1.9%  skip:58.7%  L0:44.8% L1:52.0% BI: 3.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] 8x8 transform intra:54.6% inter:85.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 30.3% 42.6% 4.6% inter: 7.
5% 12.1% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 32% 49%  8% 11%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 23% 33%  3%  2%
 2%  2%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 34% 29% 14%  3%  4%
 4%  4%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 48% 31% 18%  3%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] ref P L0: 54.3%  9.2% 25.5% 11.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] ref B L0: 80.4% 15.0%  4.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] ref B L1: 91.3%  8.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000001cd03e0] kb/s:2843.59`

Comment: Will need to see full console output to debug memory error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the `amix` filter, which defaults to ending with the longest duration:

```
ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -filter_complex "amix;blend=all_expr='A*0.5+B*0.5'" output.mp4
```

---

You can also pad the shorter audio if using your current command. Suppose v1 is the shorter video:

```
ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]apad[a];[a][1]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3;blend=all_expr='A*0.5+B*0.5'" output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you! the `amix` suggestion fixed the audio clipping but (obviously) not the panning, but the `apad` suggestion does everything I need. I really appreciate it.